# SWIG Java convert int64_t to jlong when using -DSWIGWORDSIZE64

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

## Context

I have a C++ code with overload `int` and `int64_t` that I need to wrap to Java

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

int foo(int param);
int foo(int64_t param);
};
```

and this swig

```
%{
#include <cstdint>
%}

%include "stdint.i"
%include "typemaps.i"

%ignore "";
%rename ("foo") foo(int);
%rename ("foo") foo(int64_t);

%include "foo.hpp";
```

## GCC

When using GCC int64_t will be define as long int

```sh
grepc -rn "typedef.*INT64_TYPE" /lib/gcc
/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/stdint-gcc.h:43:typedef __INT64_TYPE__ int64_t;
```

and then

```sh
gcc -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null | grep __INT64
#define __INT64_TYPE__ long int
```

So I use `-DSWIGWORDSIZE64` to avoid wrapper wrong type issue

```sh
grep "int64" -C 1 /usr/local/share/swig/4.0.1/stdint.i 
#if defined(SWIGWORDSIZE64)
typedef long int        int64_t;
#else
typedef long long int       int64_t;
#endif
```

So far so good (at least in python and csharp), BUT in Java...

## SWIG Java

in Java SWIG swig seems to wrap C++ `long int` to C Wrapper `int` (also truncating 2^64 to 2^32...)
Ref: http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java_default_primitive_type_mappings
Src: https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/java/typemaps.i

So these both methods will have the same prototype -> my current issue

AFAIK [java/typemaps.i](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/java/typemaps.i) nor [java.swg](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/java/java.swg) support the `SWIGWORDSIZE64` switch...

## Test Protocol

To reproduce the issue (ed I'm using swig 4.0.1)

```sh
mkdir -p gen
swig -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -I. -c++ -java -o gen/foo_java_wrap.cc -package com.google.Foo -module main -outdir gen foo.i
```

### Observed

```sh
foo.hpp:9: Warning 516: Overloaded method baz(int64_t) ignored,
foo.hpp:8: Warning 516: using baz(int) instead.

cat gen/main.java
...
package com.google.Foo;

public class main {
  public static int baz(int param) {
    return mainJNI.baz__SWIG_0(param);
  }

}
```

### Expected

```sh
cat gen/main.java
...
package com.google.Foo;

public class main {
  public static int baz(int param) {
    return mainJNI.baz__SWIG_0(param);
  }
  public static int baz(long param) {
    return mainJNI.baz__SWIG_1(param);
  }
}
```

So how can I deal with this issue ?

Thanks

EDIT: you can find this example here: https://github.com/Mizux/swig_java
(ed you can click on the badge to see logs/files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to reuse the `long long` typemap:

```
#ifdef SWIGWORDSIZE64

%define PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP(NEW_TYPE, TYPE)
%clear NEW_TYPE;
%apply TYPE { NEW_TYPE };
%enddef // PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP

PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP(long int, long long);
PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP(unsigned long int, long long);
#undef PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP

#endif // SWIGWORDSIZE64
```

Answer (score 0):

An **ugly** workaround is to **not** use `SWIGWORDSIZE64`, so `int64_t` will be typedef to `long long` which will be typemaped to `jlong`.
see: http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java_default_primitive_type_mappings

**BUT**, in the C++ warp file you'll have some `long long` that you need to patch (e.g. using a post process `sed -i -e 's/long long/int64_t/g'`) otherwise compilation fail since `long long` is not the same type than `int64_t` (aka `long int`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to provide your own typemap instead.

```
%include "stdint.i;"

#ifdef SWIGWORDSIZE64

%define PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP(TYPE, JNITYPE, JTYPE)
%clear TYPE;
%typemap(jstype) TYPE "JTYPE";
%typemap(javain) TYPE "$javainput";
%typemap(jtype) TYPE "JTYPE";
%typemap(jni) TYPE "JNITYPE";
%typemap(in) TYPE %{ $1 = ($1_ltype)&$input; %}
%typemap(freearg) TYPE "";
%typemap(out) TYPE %{ $result = $1; %}
%typemap(javaout) TYPE %{ return $jnicall; %}

%enddef // PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP

PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP(long int, jlong, long);
PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP(unsigned long int, jlong, long);
#undef PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP

#endif // SWIGWORDSIZE64
```